# How to catch central headset button?

Tags: java, android

I want to catch the central button press of the headset when it's pressed. I already searched on the internet and I found that one of the way is do this thing:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
            if(isRinging) {
                if(alarm.isActive())
                    alarm.cancelAlarm(this);
                else{
                    player.stop();
                    vibrator.cancel();
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

This code works but I've a problem: if I press the central button of the headset, Spotify opens.
How can I solve?

Comment: You're not consuming the event by returning `true`. Add that to the end of your `if`

Comment: If keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK i've to return true?

Comment: Yes, at the end of that code block. Take a look at `boolean onKeyDown`, it returns a boolean indicating whether it 'consumed' the event, i.e. if false, it will propagate that event to something else to take care of it, if true, the event is 'done', taken care of.